# What is the Importance of bride kicking grain bowl while entering in-laws house?

Tags: practice

Is it also practiced in new house opening ceremony? What does this act signify? Isn't it dosha towards Annapurna?

Answer (score 1):

It embodies the belief of prosperity. The ritual is [Griha pravesh](http://www.quora.com/In-the-Hindu-custom-brides-push-a-bowl-of-rice-with-their-foot-and-then-step-into-a-plate-of-kumkum-after-which-they-take-their-first-step-into-their-new-household-What-does-the-ritual-signify)[(Additional link)](http://www.iloveindia.com/indian-traditions/griha-pravesh.html) (minor edit on source from comment). The symbolism is that when a new bride comes she should bring prosperity.

Comment: That Wikipedia article isn't a very good source, because it doesn't cite any sources for its claims.  So you should try to find a better source.

Comment: I think this is a more reliable answer now. And as for sources, these have to be colloquial. I haven't come across a HinduWiki yet which would give definitive answers on religions. After all they aren't theorems

Comment: Thanks for finding more sources.  But you should also keep the Wikipedia link you had before.  I was just saying that it wasn't a good link on its own.  It still provides useful information.  In fact your answer had more information in it before you made the edit, so it would be better if you incorporated that stuff back in.

Comment: And yeah, of course these aren't theorems.  On questions that deal with specific stories or detailed tenets of Hinduism, citations of Hindu scripture are encouraged, but obviously for a question about a cultural like this more informal sources are fine.